# StatusStrip causes backgroundflickering

Tags: c#, events

I have a main form which has a StatusStrip at the bottom.
In this strip I show a label containing info about the last operation.
This is done like this:

in Form constructor:

```
console.added += new EventHandler<Eventargs>(showlast);
```

console.added is a custom event, that is executed every time something gets added to the console list.
Next the eventfunction:

```
private void showlast(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  statusStripLabel1.Text = console.clist.Last().ToString().Replace('\t','');
}
```

while clist is the listelement of the static class console that contains my console entries.

Now what happens is this: if I show an other form on top of mainform which contains code, that adds entries to the console every time the console gets updated the main form in background flickers once - like it loaded again. Since The main form is fullscreen and most of the other forms are rather tool windows this can't be overseen :)

Do you know any way to maybe not load the whole form new when the strip gets updated? (if that is the reason?). Other wise I'll just have to remove the strip - but of course I'd like to keep it :)

Thanks for your answers in advance!!

Comment: Check if the Resize event for the StatusStrip is firing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try:

1) Set `DoubleBuffered = 'True'` on `Form`.

2) Before setting `statusStripLabel1.Text`, check if existing text is not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer - but it didn't do the trick...I hadn't known DoubleBuffered before and description sound perfect for this but as I said it didn't work. Now the thing that really flickers is my main form background picture...it's actually assigned in the constructor and not in the load() method but that doensn't seem to change anything. Oh and checking the text for duplicity won't work since it's (almost) never the same.

Comment: The reason why I put point #2 was to remove if any frequent calls to that method with same value.